# Maha Ganapathi moola mantra Nyasa needed ( inlcuding Bija, Shaktih and Keelakam please)!

Tags: scripture, mantras

Maha Ganpathi moola mantra nyasa mantras varies . Please suggest the most popular or authentic Bija, Shakti and Keelakam to be used prior to japa of 28 syllable mantra

Thanks in advance